# kendo-ui: custom template with ternary operator in a grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a template for grid in kendo-ui. Its formatting is conditional...as follows:

dataset sample:

```
json: [{ "name" :"abc", "link":123 },{ "name" :"def", "link":null}...]

The template should be of the logic:

link === null ? <span>name</span> : <a target="_blank" href="http://mywebsite/name">#=name#</a>
```

i.e. conditionally make the text hyperlinked v/s display it as is (`"abc"` should be displayed with a hyperlink while `"def"` should not have a hyperlink).

I am able to get the unconditional way of template working with always make the text as hyperlink as follows:

```
var nameTemplate = '<a target="_blank" href="http://mywebsite/#=name#">#=name#</a>';
```

But cannot get the template with the above ternary operator logic to work

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function option of the **[template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)**:

```
columns: [
    "name",
    { 
      field: "link", 
      title: "link", 
      template: function(dataItem) {
        return dataItem.link === null ? "<span>" + dataItem.name + "</span>" : "<a href='http://mywebsite/" + dataItem.name + "'>" + dataItem.name + "</a>"
      }
    },
]
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EbUVo)**